# Visual Studio c++ Only in Debug Mode LNK 1104 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've just created c++ console application in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

When I run code in debug mode:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\example.exe'
```

When I run code in release mode:

```
Build: 1 succeeded
```

Do you have any idea, why would i have LNK1104 on "debug mode" ?

Comment: Did you try a clean and rebuild?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx

Comment: @NathanOliver I did 10 time clean and rebuild, including rebooting os.

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI thanks, but i already read the article and applied the rules on my project.

Comment: ***error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\example.exe'*** If this is the actual error then I can see why. You should not have permission to write to the folder C:\Users. So your project settings are wrong for the debug build.

Comment: @drescherjm i did as you say, change the project location to "Desktop" but still same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the solution.

I am currently using "Bitdefender Total Security 2015" 
and in the antivirus part,

I found the following message

[image]

So Bitdefender exactly deleted my .exe file everytime I compile in debug version.

Solution :

Go to Antivirus part:

[image]

Click excluded files and folders on Exclusion tab

[image]

Finally add your project path

[image]

I did this way and my roject also worked in debug version.

I hope the solution is helpful