# LNK1104 only happened in Debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This error only happened in Debug mode, what could be? The code is very large, cannot copy to here.
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'D:\TEST\TEST_Build.exe'

Comment: Your app may be locked by an antivirus scan. I suggest you could refer yo the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574061/visual-studio-c-only-in-debug-mode-lnk-1104-error

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-160) says:

> The two most common causes of the issue are:
>
> your program is already running or is loaded in the debugger [...]

It lists a few other possibilities, too - please follow the link.